# Angular 2 - Using an @Input to pass data into ng2-typewriter

Tags: angular

I am using **[ng2-typewriter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-typewriter)** in my project, and I want it to act as a singleton so that I can reuse it.

So far everything is okay, but I've ran into the plugin's pre-set methods and I am having a hard time implementing an **[input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)** of my own.

I want to link my `@Input firstLine: string;` to the `this.contents = this.tws.format([*]);` , but it only accepts a string value and does not react to `this.firstLine` without quotes.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TypewriterService, TypewriterContent } from 'ng2-typewriter';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'hero-typer',
    templateUrl: 'hero-typer.component.html'
})

export class HeroTyperComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() firstLine: string;

    name: string;
    contents: TypewriterContent[] = [];
    wecraft: TypewriterContent[] = [];
    isDone: boolean = false;
    _class: string = '';

    constructor(private tws: TypewriterService) {
        this.name = 'Hello Angular2';
        this.contents = this.tws.format(['First line of text ']); 
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
    this.contents.map((v: TypewriterContent, i: number) => {
        if (i === 1) {
            v.setSpecialWord('10');
        }
    });
}

onDone(isDone: boolean): void {
    if (isDone) {
        this._class = 'completed';
        this.name = 'The typewriter is done.';
        setTimeout(() => this.isDone = isDone, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: name is strongly typed here and it is of type string so how can this.firstLine accept values other than that ?

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to solve here, this is why I've made the reference. This - `this.contents = this.tws.format([this.firstLine]);` is not working with a binding to the tag, despite the fact that it accepts strings.

Comment: if you are unsure of the type why not put any instead of string

Comment: why are you using it like this ([this.firstLine])? will it not work like (this.firstLine)

Comment: @RahulSingh , this is a typewriter plugin, so I am most definitely sure that this is going to be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was that I have put the content references in the `constructor` and they are supposed to be in the `ngOnInit()` function , leaving the `constructor` for the services.

> **NOTE:** *I am still in the process of learning Angular 2. If anything in the above sentence does not make sense, please someone who understands this better, improve me on this.*

```
    export class HeroTyperComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() firstLine: string;

    name: string;
    contents: TypewriterContent[] = [];
    wecraft: TypewriterContent[] = [];
    isDone: boolean = false;
    _class: string = '';

    constructor(private tws: TypewriterService) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.contents.map((v: TypewriterContent, i: number) => {
            if (i === 1) {
                v.setSpecialWord('10');
            } 
        });
        this.name = 'Hello Angular2';
        this.contents = this.tws.format([this.firstLine]); 
    }
```